# Replacement of ESSeedInjector in storm-crawler 2.2

Tags: stormcrawler

I'm updating our crawler from storm-crawler 1.14 to 2.2. What is the replacement for the old ESSeedInjector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class-based topologies have been replaced by Flux files, which are far more flexible to use. The injection is now done as part of the crawl as you can see in [es-crawler.flux](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/external/elasticsearch/archetype/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/es-crawler.flux). It would be easy to extract the injection part and put that in a separate script if you want to keep things separate.
Alternatively, you could copy the code back from [1.14](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/1.14/external/elasticsearch/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/elasticsearch/ESSeedInjector.java), put it in your project and fix whatever needs fixing for it to work with Storm 2.x.